# How to give the user the option to make updates to or delete a node with a unique field without showing the administrative toolbar?

Tags: forms, users

I'm fairly new to Drupal and am working on a Drupal 7 site for an internship. I've created a custom content type for links to be in an A-Z link directory where both authenticated users and administrators have the permission of adding, editing, or deleting their own content. I've used the Unique Fields module to prevent nodes with the same URL from being created. I am also implementing the Workflow module to make sure an administrator oversees authenticated user's actions.

Here's the functionality I want:

Ideally, an authenticated user would be brought to a form giving them the options to add, edit, or delete a node. Is there a form module I can use to make this form self-containing, or would I have to link to corresponding pages (add content page for add, etc.)? I'd also like to implement a check in real-time on the unique field should the user choose to add a node. Again, the authenticated users are not going to have access to the administrative toolbar.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Why not just make a custom menu containing the 'Add content' link, stick it in a block, and let the user use the 'edit' tab on the node page to edit it, from where they can delete it?

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to add/edit/ delete one node at a time or see a list of many nodes with options to edit/delete existing nodes (and create new ones)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. @knowledges33ker I only want them to be able to edit one node at a time. Ideally, there would be some sort of look-up for the URL and if it already exists, give them the option to update or delete it.